# Entity Framework Detached Scenario Referenced Entity Saving Issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Hi guys Im having problem with entity framework code first in a detached scenario.
I have two Entities Order and User.
the Order class has a property of type User
so Everytime I save an Order object I have to:

```
order.UserId = order.CurrentUser.Id;
order.CurrentUser = null;
```

Im assigning the UserId of type int for foreign key purpose
but I have to null the CurrentUser Property.

Do you guys have a better way to approach this issue?

Comment: May you be more specific on how and why you setting the UserId in the Navigation property rather than the `order.UserId` property ?? if you add more code on how you bind your model that would be better.

Comment: Hi @WahidBitar i have a mapping this.HasRequired(t => t.CurrentUser)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(z => z.UserId)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: and in the Order Class I have 2 properties:  public User CurrentUser {get; set;}    public int UserId {get; set;}

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `UserId` property not the `Order` class and don't use the `Order.CurrentUser` navigation property because you do nothing with it.